# How to get n most column values from each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I know how to get most frequent value of each column in dataframe using "mode". For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]})
df.mode()
   A
0  2
```

But I am unable to find "n" most frequent value of each column of a dataframe? For example for the mentioned dataframe, i would like following output for n=2:

```
   A
0  2
1  1
```

Any pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `pd.Series.value_counts` and extract the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]})

res = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].value_counts().head(2).index for col in df})

#    A
# 0  2
# 1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and select index values by indexing, but it working for each column separately, so need `apply` or `dict comprehension` with `DataFrame contructor`. Casting to `Series` is necessary for more general solution if possible indices does not exist, e.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

N = 2
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().index[:N]))
```

Or:

```
N = 2
df = pd.DataFrame({x:pd.Series( df[x].value_counts().index[:N]) for x in df.columns})

print (df)
   A    B  C
0  2  1.0  d
1  1  NaN  e
```

For more general solution select only numeric columns first by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'C': list('abcdef')})

N = 2
df = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().index[:N]))
```

---

```
N = 2
cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
df = pd.DataFrame({x: pd.Series(df[x].value_counts().index[:N]) for x in cols})

print (df)
   A    B  C
0  2  1.0  d
1  1  NaN  e
```